# Importing `day.js` doesn't work in my extension despite being usable in the console

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, dayjs

I'm trying to use the [`day.js`](https://day.js.org/) library in my extension. Data is passed using `browser.runtime.sendMessage()` from my content script to my background script, which is where I use `day.js`.

Oddly enough, `Error: dayjs is not a function` appears in the console of the webpage where the content script runs (e.g. `google.com` rather than `about:devtools-toolbox?id=my-extension&type=extension`). I'm using Firefox.

Furthermore, I can run `dayjs()` with no problems in the console of `about:devtools-toolbox`. Why doesn't it work in my background script? And why does the error appear in the content script's context?

`background.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- Background page is necessary for supporting ES6 modules -->
    <script type="module" src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

`background.js`:

```
import * as dayjs from "./dayjs@1.11.0/dayjs.min.js";
import * as relativeTime from "./dayjs@1.11.0/relativeTime.js";

async function calculateAge(datetimeString) {
  const datetime = dayjs(datetimeString);

  dayjs.extend(relativeTime);

  const age = datetimeCreated.fromNow();
  return age;
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(calculateAge);
```

`content.js`:

```
async function getAge(datetimeString) {
  const age = await browser.runtime.sendMessage(datetimeString);
  return age;
}
```

`manifest.json`:

```
"background": {
  "page": "background.html"
},

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*"]
  }
],
```

Comment: The file you import is not a ES module, it's just a js file that uses `require` system or globalThis.dayjs. The error is shown in the web page because Firefox, being smart, transfers the error via messaging.

Comment: In that case, should I switch to a different library that supports ES modules? Also, why would `dayjs()` work from the console if it doesn't work from within `background.js`?

Comment: `"background": {"scripts": ["vendor/dayjs.min.js"]}` or something like that depending on where the file is.

Comment: The script you currently import simply sets a global variable on `window` or `globalThis`, which is why it works in console.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! Would I be able to use `window`/`globalThis` in `background.js`, or do I have to switch libraries/use webpack?

Comment: In Firefox/ManifestV2 both should work. In MV3 service worker only `globalThis` or `self` work.

Comment: It works now, thank you!! If you'd like to post an answer with the info, I'll accept it.